# Android, relativelayout height exceeding the screen

Tags: android

relativelayout height, how do I capture when the height is larger than the screen?
my_rl.getheight() does not work, returned size is the height of the screen, not my relativelayout.
Thanks.

Comment: How is it being created?

Comment: RL_SV = new RelativeLayout(AddActivity.this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams RL_SV_PARAM = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RL_SV_PARAM.topMargin = (int)RlSvTop;
RL_OPT.addView(RL_SV,RL_SV_PARAM);

Answer (score 0):

Try using `View.getMeasuredHeight()` instead. [Explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SizePaddingMargins).

Comment: View.getMeasuredHeight(), returned size is the height of the screen, not my relativelayout. Not work.